# Passing Arrays to blazors IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I wonder what is the best way to pass an array to `IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync`.
The problem I stumbled upon is that blazor will pass each element of the array as a parameter to the javascript function since InvokeAsync has an open parameter list and will not know if you just passed arguments of the same type or an array.

For now I just go with a second parameter like `InvokeAsync("functionname", array, false)`.

Any other suggestions? Better solutions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd either have to cast your array to `object`* or call the Extension method directly:

```cs
var array = Array.Empty<Baz>();
// Casting to object
JS.InvokeAsync<Foo>("bar", (object)array);

// Explicitly call the extension method:
JSRuntimeExtensions.InvokeAsync<Foo>(JS, "bar", array);
```

Or just use the overload it thinks you are attempting to call:

```cs
JS.InvokeAsync<Foo>("bar", new object[] { array });
```

<sub>* Based on my limited knowledge of [C#'s Overload Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/overload-resolution).</sub>

Comment: The confusion is because JSRuntime passes the argument as json. So I switched to passing `new[] { array }` if there is just one array parameter.